# Proving Continuity Using $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}f(x+\Delta x)-f(x) = 0$

Tags: limits, continuity

I am trying to prove a simple problem that the function $y=x^2$ is continuous by using the fact that if

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0}f(x+\Delta x)-f(x) = 0$$

Then the function will be continuous. My proof goes:

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0} (x + \Delta x)^2 - x^2 = \lim_{\Delta x\to0}2x\Delta x + (\Delta x)^2 = 2\lim_{\Delta x\to0}x \Delta x + \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\Delta x = 0 $$

Does this correctly demonstrate continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. You showed that $\lim_{x\to a} x^2 = a^2 $ for all $a$. If that equality holds for all $a$ in its domain, then the function is continuous.